# Вывод нужных постов в слайдер

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть рубрики и страницы нужно по выбору выводить заголовок и картинку поста в слайдер, сделать чекбокс для каждой записи по которой будет выводится запись в слайдер в шапке.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Метки использовать не получится они уже используются.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не мешало бы чуть подробнее текстом расписать, что, всё же, вам нужно (:

Comment: вывести записи в слайдер только те у которых  включен чекбокс. Тоесть если у записи в произвольном поле чекбокс true то выводим запись в слайдер

Comment: Это лучше в сам вопрос добавить)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class="top-slider hide-1200">
        <?php
        // запрос
        $wpb_all_query = new WP_Query(array('meta_key' => '_slider_confirm','post_type'=>'any', 'post_status'=>'publish', 'posts_per_page'=>-1));
        ?>
        <?php if ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts()  ) : ?>
                <!-- the loop -->
                <?php while ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : $wpb_all_query->the_post(); ?>

                <div class="top-slider-item" style="background-image: url('img/@2x/1.jpg') ">
                    <div class="top-slider-item_card">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
                <!-- end of the loop -->

            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        <?php else : ?>
            <p><?php _e( 'Извините, нет записей, соответствуюших Вашему запросу.' ); ?></p>
        <?php endif; ?>

    </div>
```

Решил так вроде все работает. Подскажите как можно еще сделать и что поправить ?